# Building Regional Climate Model

Tags: model, weather

How do I begin to build a regional climate model? Not quite sure how to do downscaling on the GCM or how to build a regional climate model. I want to build a regional climate model of the valdivian region of chile that will have prediction power.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: hey! I would be more than happy to do that, but I'm at the initial stages of just trying to understand the math/science behind it to enable myself to write some code. >.< I wasn't quite sure where to go with my question so I posted it here. I know I am being vague and I apologize. I am just starting my thesis, and I'm a bit lost. >.<

Answer (score 0):

Some basic stuff to do with GCM and RGM's are all based around Multiple Linear Regression.

Statistical downscaling can be done using these tools to predict the larger scale atmospheric processes and extrapolate it further in time.

To go about Multiple/Single linear regression for climate modelling you need to split the dataset between test and predict. That means if you have 40 years of daily temperature data, use the first 30 years to run the linear regression. Then, with the results of the regression see how accurate you can predict the final 10 years you left out. If all going well you get some decent results, then it wouldn't be too big of a stretch to expand it for the next 10 years.

Of course this is a very rudimentary basics and there are plenty of papers out there that comment on statistical downscaling for RGM's. SPSS has some good tools for multiple linear regression and can be used to predict the future data. For a thesis, in my opinion, it's always good to comment on uncertainty with the models.

It really depends what route you want to go down. If you're using your own data then it would be 'simple' enough to create a basic model to 'predict' temperature changes or anything along them lines.

Just realised this post is from 2016, but hey-ho here we are incase anyone else would like to use it in he future!